# CSS obtener valor de propiedad según el nombre de la clase

Tags: html, css, css3

Me encuentro con la siguiente situación: creo con JavaScript un numero variable de elementos cuya clase es `order-${incrementar++}` la regla CSS para esta clase de ve tener esta lógica: para `order-1`:

```
.order-1{
 order: 1;
}
```

para `order -2`:

```
.order-2{
 order: 2;
}
```

y así sucesivamente. Quiero dar solución a este problema solo con CSS, una solución que he encontrado es usar `attr()` de CSS, pero no funciona como puede ver a continuación:

```css
.container{
 display:flex;
}

.order{
 order: attr(data-order);
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div data-order="3" class="order">ultimo</div>
   <div data-order="2" class="order">intermedio</div>
    <div data-order="1" class="order">primero</div>
</div>
```

Esto debería funcionar pues en [MDN se dice que `atrr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/attr) es valida para todas las propiedades CSS. Si hace funcionar `atrr()` en `order`, es la solución a esta cuestión. Pero si también se puede dar solución a esta cuestión con otra técnica CSS, su ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano.

### Update

Despues de investigar mas sobre attr() de CSS, me doy cuenta de que ya no esta soportada por los navegadores.

```css
.background {
  background-color: red;
}

.background[data-background] {
  background-color: attr(data-background color, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="background" data-background="lime">background expected to be red if your browser does not support advanced usage of attr()</div>
```

Comment: Hummm... te suena el atributo style?, creo que pasa eso esta pensado.

Comment: Si eso funciona, al generar los elementos html con javascript hago element.style=`order: ${incrementar++}` . Los elementos se ordenan. No me gusta este metodo por que el atributo style tiene prioridad sobre los estilos de clases. si en algun momento creara una clase order especifica para un elemento, esta quedaria anulada por los estilos en style. Por esta razon busco una solucion con clases CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que te puedo mostrar que funciona, algo pasa con la implementación de atrr() que por el momento solo funciona con `content` y en pseudoclases, parece que no esta 100% implementado

```css
.demo{
     width:var(--w );
     height:var(--h );
     margin: 5px;
   
      display:block;
      background:green;  
   }
```

```html
<div class="demo" style="--w:200px;--h:100px;">
  prueba 1
</div>
<div class="demo" style="--w:300px;--h:100px;">
  prueba 2
</div>
```

espero pueda serte de ayuda.

no hay que olvidar que esta es una implementación relativamente nueva
referencia: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#attr-notation